# Can I change AutoCommit property of a JDBC connection multiple times

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

I am dealing with a Connection Pool that only creates connections with "autoCommit=true".

However, for my specific use case, I need "autoCommit=false" so that I can set the "fetch size" property on the JDBC statements.

My initial tests tests indicate that I can set the AutoCommit property on the JDBC Connection instance, and then reset it again before returning the connection to the pool.

```
Connection conn = pool.getConnection();
try {

   conn.setAutoCommit(false);

   // execute queries for my use case using above connection.

} finally {

   conn.setAutoCommit(true);

   // do other cleanup like statement and result set close
}

pool.returnConnection(conn);
```

Does anybody know if this is a correct use case?

I am using Postgres, but may migrate to Oracle later on.

Comment: This is specified in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-) (see **NOTE**). If that doesn't fully answer, could you be more specific what you are trying to achieve. Note though that sometimes connection pools don't allow `autoCommit` at all, and sometimes connection pools manage transactions for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final update**: yes you can change autoCommit multiple times, you can also workaround it using the commit/rollback command in a statement as you discovered. My advise is to stick with autoCommit set to false and always use transactions where you need them.

I'm also using Postgres and Oracle and I'm always using autocommit = false, since I cannot manage trasactions with autocommit = true

You can change autocommit as you tested but I encourage you to manage transactions explicitly even if it's a single statement.

If you can use a framework like Spring (or Guice) there is transaction management made via AOP and you don't need to bother with commit and rollback instructions.

In Oracle commit time does not depend to the amount of data committed and committing with an higher frequency (with respect to functional requirements) can also hurt performance.

**Update**: From your comment you state that Postgres respects transaction boundaries in autocommit; I cannot reproduce the behaviour here is a simple test case:

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestPostgresAutocommit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://pgdev/dbxxx","xxx","xxx");
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        Connection connection2= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://pgdev/dbxxx","xxx","xxx");
        connection2.setAutoCommit(true);        
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            statement.execute("insert into test_gc(col1,col2) values ("+ i + "," + "'" + i + "')");
        }
        statement.close();
        countElements(connection2);
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("delete from test_gc");
        statement.close();
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("begin");
        statement.close();
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            statement.execute("insert into test_gc(col1,col2) values ("+ i + "," + "'" + i + "')");
        }
        connection.rollback();
        countElements(connection2);

    }

    private static void countElements(Connection connection2) throws Exception {
        Statement statement2=connection2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=statement2.executeQuery("select count(*) from test_gc");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("row num in table=" + rs.getInt(1)); 
        rs.close();
        statement2.close();

    }

}
```

the program fails to rollback with an Exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot rollback when autoCommit is
>   enabled.

So it's not possible to manage transactions when autoCommit is true; did you find something different?

**Update II**: Even with this code that I think it reflects the data in your comment I got the Exception:

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestPostgresAutocommit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("start");
        Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://pgdev/dbxxx","xxx","xxx");
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        Connection connection2= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://pgdev/dbdxxx","xxx","xxx");
        connection2.setAutoCommit(true);        
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            statement.execute("insert into test_gc(col1,col2) values ("+ i + "," + "'" + i + "')");
        }
        statement.close();
        countElements(connection2);
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("delete from test_gc");
        statement.close();
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("begin");
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            statement.execute("insert into test_gc(col1,col2) values ("+ i + "," + "'" + i + "')");
        }
        connection.rollback();
        countElements(connection2);

    }

    private static void countElements(Connection connection2) throws Exception {
        Statement statement2=connection2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=statement2.executeQuery("select count(*) from test_gc");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("row num in table=" + rs.getInt(1)); 
        rs.close();
        statement2.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither Spring nor any other framework can be used here.   I am finding out in my tests that even though autoCommit = true, the postgres does respect transaction boundaries whenever they are set.   Was that not your experience as well? Or was it an oracle test.

Comment: @Mecon that was not my experience, I updated the response with a test case

Comment: In the main method, before the second for loop, you create a brand new statement. On this statement, the "begin" isn't being issues. If "begin" had been issued, then the explicit transaction boundary would've been Statement is set, and this would've allowed postgres to rollback.   Could you please confirm?

Comment: If I commit the  the 2 lines after the begin command (close + create statement) the result is the same, Exception

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but let me elaborate: Here is the line I think we need before the second "for loop":   statement.execute("begin");         if you add this line before the second "for loop", postgres will respect transaction boundaries, and rollback will occur OK.   Please let me know if you too see the same?  if not, please update your code?

Comment: @Mecon response updated. I added the new code snippet

Comment: Sorry, I see the mismatch now. I am doing: statement.execute("rollback")   When I do statement-begin  and statement-rollback, the transaction boundaries are respected.

Comment: I know we ended up in this discussion, but my main questions was "Can I change AutoCommit property of a JDBC connection multiple times"

Comment: thanks so much for your help so far. Any other thoughts please let me know.