# WSO2 - Receiving exception during startup - WSO2 service

Tags: redhat, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am receiving the following warning stack trace when starting up WSO2:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-20 14:53:46,020]  WARN {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl} -  Rollback failed on removing node information node id: NODEwso2-manager.dev.reach.ie.local/10.3.30.202 {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl}
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot rollback when autoCommit is enabled.
```

Followed by:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-20 14:53:46,025] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.server.Main} -  Exception during startup. Triggering shutdown  {org.wso2.andes.server.Main}
org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:308)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startup(Broker.java:110)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.startBroker(Main.java:217)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.execute(Main.java:206)
```

and

```
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Error occurred while removing node information node id: NODEwso2-manager.dev.reach.ie.local/10.3.30.202
```

I'm just asking for some guidance as to what the issue might be.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL as your DB for storing registry artifacts? If Yes then check your DB first there might be issues with the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set your connection string to autocommit a false.

Take a look to [Can I change AutoCommit property of a JDBC connection multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321196/can-i-change-autocommit-property-of-a-jdbc-connection-multiple-times).

and the configuration docs

https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/87687527